# Concatenating merged cells with google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a use case where I need to concatenate values from merged cell with other columns based on condition

| Name | Frequency | Old Measure | New Measure | What's needed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name1 | Freq1 | Mea1 |  | Name1-Freq1-Mea1 |
|  | Freq2 |  | Nmea1 | Name1-Freq2-Nmea1 |
|  | Freq3 | Mea2 |  | Name1-Freq3-Mea2 |
| Name2 | Freq4 | Mea3 |  | Name2-Freq4-Mea3 |
|  | Freq5 |  | Nmea2 | Name2-Freq5-Nmea2 |
| Name3 | Freq6 | Mea4 |  | Name3-Freq6-Mea4 |
| Name4 | Freq7 |  | Nmea3 | Name4-Freq7-Nmea3 |
| Name5 | Freq8 |  | Nmea4 | Name5-Freq8-Nmea4 |
|  | Freq9 |  | Nmea5 | Name5-Freq9-Nmea5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |

The formula should check for column `Old Measure` and `New Measure` which ever is filled should concatenate with `Name` and `Frequency`.

I did try to take the answer from this similar question - [Concatenate merged cells with Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63684023/concatenate-merged-cells-with-google-sheets)

and added the check for `Old Measure` and `New Measure` column as below but not giving correct results.

`=IFS(C1<>"", TEXTJOIN("-",false,INDEX(A:A,LARGE((ISBLANK(A:A)=FALSE)*(ROW(A:A)<=ROW())*ROW(A:A),1)),B1,C1) , D1<>"", TEXTJOIN("-",false,INDEX(A:A,LARGE((ISBLANK(A:A)=FALSE)*(ROW(A:A)<=ROW())*ROW(A:A),1)),B1,D1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(query(byrow(
{lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/(A2:A<>""),A2:A),B2:D},
lambda(r,textjoin("-",1,r))),
"limit "&-1+max(if(B2:D<>"",row(B2:D)))))
```

[image]

### Explanation

This part

```
lookup(row(A2:A),row(A2:A)/(A2:A<>""),A2:A)
```

Fills the gaps in A2:A with the last non-empty value above.

Then

```
byrow(...,lambda(r,textjoin("-",1,r)))
```

Concatenates row-by-row the values from the previous array and the values in B2:D.

And finally

```
query(...,"limit "&-1+max(if(B2:D<>"",row(B2:D)))
```

Constrains the resulting array to the last filled row.

Comment: This works amazingly well. Thank you genius @ztiaa! , How can I limit the range to just the table or where the last entry of ```Old Measure``` or ```New Measure``` is dynamically because the entries may expand and also there may be another different table below this table which we don't want to get into the range

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Try to change the last two instances of B2:D to C2:D.

Comment: Got it, I shall check add a check so that the formula checks for the last entry in the last two columns and only have the range til there